# Jacoco Merge goal, is not taking the input file path provided

Tags: maven, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have given the following configuration in the jacoco merge goal

```
<configuration> 
    <fileSets> <!-- Implementation attribute not needed in Maven 3 --> 
        <fileSet> 
            <directory>${project.build.directory}/coverage-reports/</directory> 
        <includes> 
             <include>*.exec</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet> 
</fileSets> 
<!-- File containing the merged data --> 
<destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-merged/merged.exec</destFile>
```

But it keeps looking for exec file in ../target/jacoco.exec during merge, and skips the merge goal with no exec files found for merge.

I am using maven 3.3.9 and Jacoco Maven plugin 0.7.8.